# Supremum of certain modified zeta functions at 1

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, dirichlet-series

Let $D$ be an integer number and let $\chi$ be the Dirichlet character defined by 
$$\chi(m) = 0 \text{ if $m$ even, } \chi(m) = (D/m) \text{ if $m$ odd,}$$
where $(D/m)$ denotes the Jacobi symbol. Let us denote by $\zeta_D(s)$ its L-series:
$$ \zeta_D(s) = L(s,\chi) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{\chi(n)}{n^s} = \prod_p \frac{1}{1-(D/p)p^{-s}},$$
where $(D/p) = 0$ if $p | 2d$.

For $s > 1$ there are the following bounds:
$$\frac{\zeta(2s)}{\zeta(s)} = \prod_p \frac{1}{1+p^{-s}} \leq \zeta_D(s) \leq \prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}} = \zeta(s).$$
Both of them become trivial for $s = 1$. Still, $\zeta_D(1)$ is a finite positive number for $D < 0$.

> Consider the sequence
>   $$ \zeta_{-d}(1),\, d = 1,2,3,\ldots$$ 
>   Is this sequence bounded above or below? If yes, what is an upper or lower bound?

Comment: Dirichlet $L$-functions at $1$ can get arbitrarily large or small.   Search under "extreme values of Dirichlet L-functions".

Comment: For $D$ odd $\chi(m) = (D/m)$ is a primitive character modulo $D$ or $4D$ why do you replace it by the non primitive character $ (D/m) 1_{gcd(m,2)=1}$. And the Siegel zero problem is exactly about that

Comment: Unless there is a good reason to assume the opposite, you probably should not expect this sequence to be bounded. Generally speaking, there is a rather large proportion of Dirichlet L-function (with a given conductor) which has a "large" value at 1. See for example Theorem 2 in this recent paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.00760